# MFCC Deltas, Delta-Deltas

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, mfcc, speech-processing, cepstral-analysis

I have just a quick question about how to calculate Deltas from MFCC. I have found the formula for calculating deltas [here](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/#deltas-and-delta-deltas):

$$d_t=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}n\left(c_{t+n}-c_{t-n}\right)}{2\sum_{n=1}^{N}n^2}$$

Another source states it is a regression equation. From what I can see, it takes coefficient from a previous and next frame. For any $N$ e.g. $N=2$, $t-n$ in $c_{t-n}$ can refer to the past where there are no frames. Which values should I substitute in this case? Should it be simply 0?

Similarly, when $t+n$ in $c_{t+n}$ refers to a frame in future that not exists, should it also be 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to copy first frame and last frame values to extend vector sequence beyond boundaries than to assign 0. This could be implemented just by adjusting indexes:

```
if (index1 < 0)
    index1 = 0
if (index2 > N - 1)
   index2 = N - 1

delta = v[index1] - v[index2]
```

Comment: Yes. 0 are not typical values for MFCC, so using 0 for the first/last frames would give spurious values of the delta value.